# Could not get uid/gid when building Node/Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app, react-scripts

My Dockerfile is using alpine and globally installing react-scripts.  When it tries to install it, it fails with "could not get uid/gid" error.  I added the "---unsafe-perm" option to the npm install -g command. The docker container is successfully created, but the permissions in the container are messaged up for the installed files.  I see the username and group set to 1000 for all of them.  I tried adding the following command to the Dockerfile right before the install step but that didn't help.

```
RUN npm -g config set user root
```

Build error

```
Error: could not get uid/gid
[ 'nobody', 0 ]

    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/uid-number/uid-number.js:37:16
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:296:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:250:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:76:20
    at cb (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:228:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:266:24
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:83:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:82:13
    at f (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:173:20)
    at Conf.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/config/core.js:231:22)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205
  if (npm.config.get('json')) {
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:205:18)
    at process.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at process._fatalException (internal/bootstrap/node.js:472:27)
ERROR: Service 'sample-app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g' returned a non-zero code:
```

Dockerfile

```
/usr/src/app # cat Dockerfile
# build environment
FROM node:10-alpine as builder
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /usr/src/app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@1.1.1 -g 
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm run build

# production environment
FROM nginx:1.13.9-alpine
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

**UPD** Fixed [in `nodejs@12.4.0`](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/813#issuecomment-590599414)?

Check if this is linked to [nodejs/docker-node issue 813](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/813#issuecomment-407339011):

> Root cause seems to be: [Thread stack size](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/functional-differences-from-glibc.html#Thread_stack_size)
>
> > The default stack size for new threads on `glibc` is determined based on the resource limit governing the main thread’s stack (`RLIMIT_STACK`).
> >     It generally ends up being 2-10 MB.
>
> There three possible solutions:
>
> - Talk to Alpine teams to fix it. There were [some discussions already](https://github.com/voidlinux/void-packages/issues/4147)
> - Fix it in the [node docker alpine image as follows](https://github.com/jubel-han/dockerfiles/blob/master/node/Dockerfile)
> - Set default `npm_config_unsafe_perm=true` in the docker image as a workaround until it's fixed.

You already tried the third option, but consider also:

> Alternatively, you should switch to the slim (Debian) variant until this get's fixe upstream by the Alpine team.

Comment: `RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true` in docker file before npm install

Comment: I went for the third option, it worked like a charm. For my use any performance decrease was insignificant

Answer (score 20):

I faced same issue in Docker for node-alpine image when I am dockerizing my react application

I resolved with following dockerfile configuration.

```
FROM node:8.10.0-alpine

# Set a working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./build/package.json .
COPY ./build/yarn.lock .

# To handle 'not get uid/gid'
RUN npm config set unsafe-perm true

# Install Node.js dependencies
RUN yarn install --production --no-progress

# Copy application files
COPY ./build .

# Install pm2
RUN npm install -g pm2 --silent


# Run the container under "node" user by default
USER node

CMD ["pm2", "start", "mypm2config.yml", "--no-daemon", "--env", "preprod"]
```